# problems understanding what exactly the error for this kivy program is telling me

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to learn how to incorporate screens into my kivy code and I thought I had it down, but I keep getting this error and I can not understand what it is telling me. This is on macos running Python version 3.7.9. This code was running fine before I added PyPage2, but even after I remove the new changes I still get this error just on a different line. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/lees/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-12-14_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 07:22:35) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/lees/Desktop/github/CN_Tut/src/main.py", line 173, in <module>
     ''')
   File "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 510, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "/Users/lees/opt/anaconda3/envs/CN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 673, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code is below:

````
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string('''
<WelcomeScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text_size: self.size
            font_size: 48
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'center'
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Welcome to Code Ninja's Programming"
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 1, 0.8
            GridLayout:
                rows: 4
                cols: 1
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 1
                    cols: 2
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.4, 1
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'PythonPages'
                    Label:
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: 38
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'center'
                        text: "Python"
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 1
                    cols: 2
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.4, 1
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'CPPProgramming'
                    Label:
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: 38
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'center'
                        text: "C++"
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 1
                    cols: 2
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.4, 1
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'CSProgramming'
                    Label:
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: 38
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'center'
                        text: "C#"
                GridLayout:
                    rows: 1
                    cols: 2
                    Button:
                        size_hint: 0.4, 1
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'JavaProgramming'
                    Label:
                        text_size: self.size
                        font_size: 38
                        halign: 'left'
                        valign: 'center'
                        text: "Java"
            Label:
                size_hint: 1, 0.2
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: 28
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'center'
                color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                text: "\\nThis program is to show how much everyone has to learn when it comes to programming in these four languages. Click a button to the left to start! "
<PythonPages>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'

<PyPage1>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "PyPage1"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage2'

<PyPage2>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Hello World"

<CPPProgramming>:
        GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
<CSProgramming>:
        GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
<JavaProgramming>:
        GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
            ''')


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class PythonPages(Screen):
    pass


class PyPage1(Screen):
    pass


class PyPage2(Screen):
    pass


class CPPProgramming(Screen):
    pass


class CSProgramming(Screen):
    pass


class JavaProgramming(Screen):
    pass


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        screenman = ScreenManager()
        screenman.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='menu'))
        screenman.add_widget(PythonPages(name='PythonPages'))
        screenman.add_widget(PyPage1(name='PyPage1'))
        screenman.add_widget(CPPProgramming(name='CPPProgramming'))
        screenman.add_widget(CSProgramming(name='CSProgramming'))
        screenman.add_widget(JavaProgramming(name='JavaProgramming'))
        return screenman


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
        ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is incorrect indentation in your `kv` string.

Try changing the final few rules should be::

```
<CPPProgramming>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
<CSProgramming>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
<JavaProgramming>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 1
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            size: self.texture_size
            font_size: 38
            color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Hello World"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: "forward"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'PyPage1'
```